# How do I test the number of requests sent to the server in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

Does anyone know how I can test how many requests are sent using the Jasmine $httpBackend object?

I have a kendo grid that is built using data obtained from a RESTful service.

The grid also has pre-filtering capabilities. This means that you can declare a set of criteria then, when the grid is built, the criteria are sent to the server along with the request for the data.

The data should then be filtered by the RESTful service before sending the response back. Thus the response will contain only data only that meets the criteria.

The problem is that currently two requests are being sent: one for the data and then another one for the criteria.

I want to write a test that makes sure only one request is sent, for the original data, and that the filtering is done by the RESTful service.

Here is my test:

```
it('should send only one request to the server when getting data to build the grid', function () {
    angular.mock.inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();

        // THE CRITERIA
        scope.myCriteria = {
            "operator": "and",
            "operands": [
                {
                    "property": "accountId",
                    "value": "1",
                    "constraint": "contains",
                    "ignoreCase": "true"
                }
            ]
        };

        // THE ORIGINAL DATA
        var respondData = [
            {accountId: '1', name: 'Account 1', status: 'active'},
            {accountId: '3', name: 'Account 3', status: 'active'},
            {accountId: '4', name: 'Account 4', status: 'active'}
        ];

        // THE REQUEST TO GET THE DATA
        $httpBackend.when('GET', "api/grid/accounts?crit=substringof('1',accountId)+eq+true").respond(respondData);

        // BUILD THE GRID 
        // sg-data is the data from the RESTful service. 
        // sg-filters is the filtering criteria
        var elem = $compile('<div sg-grid sg-data="api/grid/accounts" sg-columns="accountId,name,shortName,status" sg-filters="myCriteria"></div>')(scope);

        $rootScope.$apply();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        /*
         I want to do something like this:
         expect($httpBackend.requests.length).toBe(1);
        */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `expect` instead of `when` because you want to assert which requests are sent.

```
$httpBackend.expect('GET', "api/grid/accounts?crit=substringof('1',accountId)+eq+true").respond(respondData);
...
$httpBackend.flush();
...
$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
```

The last line verifies that the code has made the first request. By using `expect` instead of `when` we verify that a second request is not made. If the code would make a second request, you'd get a 'no more request expected' error.

They describe the difference between request expectations (`$httpBackend.expect`) and backend definitions (`$httpBackend.when`) in the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend)

> Request expectations
>   provide a way to make assertions about requests made by the
>   application and to define responses for those requests. The test will
>   fail if the expected requests are not made or they are made in the
>   wrong order.
>
> Backend definitions allow you to define a fake backend for your
>   application which doesn't assert if a particular request was made or
>   not, it just returns a trained response if a request is made. The test
>   will pass whether or not the request gets made during testing.

Comment: Just to add to the above answer, when I checked the documentation I found this too: afterEach(function() {
                  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
                  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
                });

Comment: You are right, I've added the `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` to the answer